# Signal processing for audio and speech

Tags: audio, sound, speech-processing

I have started learning about signals and I am interested in sound signals.

There are some questions that I need to resolve. For example in music, difference of notes like 'sol' and 'la' are about difference in frequency. But which features of signals reveal differences between piano and guitar. What sound features distinguish between two different syllables?

Can you give me a good learning source about audio processing?

Comment: You question covers at least a half dozen subject areas covered by perhaps hundreds of textbooks.  Audiology, human speech production and therapy, phonetics, speech recognition and synthesis, psychology of hearing and music, physics of sound and music, music production and synthesis, audio DSP, and etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In line with a previous similar question here are my suggestions:

There are so many nice books but I believe you should first have a look at **the science of sound** from Rossing for getting the most broad view on the subject.

Then you can look at the following books , each dealing with a particular dimension of the problem:

1- Acoustics_BERANEK

2- Elements of Acoustical Engineering_OLSON

3- Music, Physics and Engineering_OLSON

4- Art of Digital Audio_WATKINSON

5- Audio Engineering_SINCLAIR

6- Digital Audio Effects_ZÖLZER

7- Digital Audio Signal Processing_ZÖLZER

8- Fundamentals of Acoustic Signal Processing_TOHYAMA

9- Audio Signal Procesing and Coding_SPANIAS

10- Audio Programming Book_BOULANGER

11- PsychoAcoustics_ZWICKER

12- Acoustics and PsychoAcoustics_HOWARD

EDIT:
I'm sorry that I've forgotten to mention about books on **speech processing**, so here you can find a list:

1- Speech and Audio Signal Processing_GOLD

2- Speech and Hearing for Communication_FLETCHER

3- Discrete Time Processing of Speech Signals_PROAKIS

4- Fundamentals of Speech Recognition_RABINER

5- Introduction to Digital Speech Processing_RABINER

Comment: thanks for your answer. il wait for more answers and after that I will accept it.

Comment: @virtouso I've added books for speech processing exclusively.

Comment: That's a great list I will look into little by little. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> But which features of signals reveal differences between piano and guitar

Look at things like [timbre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbre); basically, most things when excited to oscillate will not only produce a single tone, but a set of overtones, too, and those are weighted differently; also, there tends to be a different temporal "decaying" and frequency changing after excitation.

Comment: I would suggest adding some sort of definition for the term *overtone*...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a series of [tutorial videos on Speech and Audio Processing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjzm7S__kBU) by Professor E. Ambikairajah; about 1 hour each. They can serve as a basis to focus on more specific topic.

- [Speech and Audio Processing 1: Introduction to Speech Processing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjzm7S__kBU)
- [Speech and Audio Processing 2: Speech Analysis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_mSQ7tTlvQ)
- [Speech and Audio Processing 3: Linear Predictive Coding (LPC)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWH-Oh5KnNY)
- [Speech and Audio Processing 4: Speech Coding I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRhkzeeMqVk&index=4&list=PLA480D1979B10D8F5)
- [Speech and Audio Processing 5: Time-Frequency Analysis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwWKTTzcg_M)
- [Speech and Audio Processing 6: Auditory Masking & Wideband Audio Coding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9qNuyD7xdg)

As for a book, [Applied Speech and Audio Processing : With Matlab Examples](http://assets.cambridge.org/97805215/19540/frontmatter/9780521519540_frontmatter.pdf) by I. McLoughlin can be a start, and you can practice with little coding abilities with Matlab, a prototyping software used in signal processing.